# Setting Tesseract to better detect a specific image

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I have an image (label of a microscopy slide), which I thought would be easy to OCR, because it is easily readable for humans. I am using the latest Tesseract V5 as a command line under Windows
However, with

```
tesseract image.jpg image.txt --oem 1 --psm x
```

with "--psm x" x being any number, which I tried, the result is poor.
Is there anything I can do to improve the results?
[image: Label of microscope slide]